# Dynamically added directive is not interpolated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts

I have a call stack like below and problem is that directive template is not interpolated. So as a result of this I can see `{{ data | json }}` as a string and `ng-repeat` is not triggered. How to approach this?

Context of situation is that I have a Highchart's chart where I need to provide clickable plot lines. On line click I need to display popover with dynamic content.

Optional question to answer:
My play with events is working well but I'm not sure if it's also well done. I would welcome any criticism on that. Idea is to hide popover on all following clicks.

Code:

1.

```
series: {events: {click: function(e) {drillDownCall(e, dataGroups)}
```

2.

```
function drillDownCall (e, dataGroups) {
  var elem = angular.element('#drilldown');
  if (!elem[0]) {
    elem = angular.element('<drilldown fancy-name="dataGroups"></drilldown>');
  }

  elem.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: e.pageY,
    left: e.pageX,
    width: '150px',
    height: '250px',
    zIndex: '2000',
    background: 'red'
  });

  var body = angular.element(document).find('body').eq(0);
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  scope.dataGroups = dataGroups;
  body.append($compile(elem)(scope));
}
```

3.

```
.directive('drilldown', [
  '$compile',
  '$window',
  function (
    $compile,
    $window
  ) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        data: '=fancyName'
      },

      template: '' +
        '<div id="drilldown">{{ data | json }}' +
          '<ul>' +
            '<li ng-repeat="group in data">{{ group.name }}</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
        '</div>',

      link: function (scope, element) {
        var ele = $compile(element)(scope),
          off;

        angular.element($window).on('click', function(e) {
          scope.$emit('drilldown::click');
        });
        off = scope.$on('drilldown::click', function() {
          angular.element(ele).remove();
          angular.element($window).off('click');
          off();
        });
      }
    };
  }]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable test it myself but I think I know why.

Start of everything is `drillDownCall` and it is called by an event that is outside of Angular.js digest cycle. So Angular.js has no idea that there is a change in scope, and doesn't run a digest cycle, causing the new directive appear as non-compiled bunch of strings. (yes even you used `$compile` it works like that)

In summary, if I remember correct, you need at least one digest cycle to see that directive compiled. To trigger a digest cycle, you can add
`$rootScope.$apply()` or `$rootScope.$applyAsync()` or anything equivalent to it to the end of `drillDownCall` event handler.

Can you please try this?

Comment: Hey. I just reached the same conclusion :). Ended up with wrapping `body.append($compile(elem)(scope));` with `scope.$apply(fn(){})`. Thx for your replay.

BTW, can you tell something about the design of whole solution? Is this good approach?